# Connecting React to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect a React Front end to Google Cloud Platform , which is hosting the Backend of my project.
I already added this servlets but I am really lost.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>react</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.html</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>react</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Have you checked this [tutorial](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/deploying-react-app-to-google-app-engine-a6ea0d5af132)? It may help you. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: so i saw it but it didnt fit my problem i think. What i have done now is to send all 404 request to the index that have the routing and then let the index handle the problem

Comment: Could you please explain, what errors are you getting or where are you stuck? Could you please provide the steps you have done until now ? In which language your backend app is implemented?

Comment: now It is working. the backend is in java.

Comment: thanks for letting me know, you can post an answer sharing what solved your issue to help other Community Members.